# What is the physical path of google drive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, google-drive

I want to link my google drive account to Notepad++ so that I can keep all my notes in cloud.

There is setting in notepad++ where I can give cloud path but I am not sure where exactly google-drive path is mapped on my local drive on Ubuntu 18.04

I see only this path in file explorer but this doesn't work in notepad++

`google-drive://my-email-id@gmail.com`

what is the physical path of google drive?

Comment: You should be able to find it quite simply by opening Files, mounting the drive and hovering over the Google-Drive icon. It will show something like //your_email_address@gmail.com

Comment: I tried that but it shows as mentioned in the post `google-drive://my-email-id@gmail.com` but notepad++ needs something like `/home/user/some-path`

Comment: I checked properties of mounted drive and it shows folder as `Folder (inode/directory)`

Comment: nice!! yes @starkus its there, but it contains more directories with some random junk names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to figure out which UID the current user is assigned to.

`loginctl list-sessions` will show you something like

***SESSION  UID USER   SEAT  TTY 
 
                    1 1001 name seat0 tty2 

1 sessions listed.***

Now you know the UID you need to know where your google-drive is mounted to.

Google drive is getting mounted using `gvfs` with:
 
`gio mount google-drive://YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com/`
to:

> /run/user/UID/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=YOURUSERNAME

So, if your UID is 1000 - the path would be: `/run/user/1000`, if your UID is 1001 - the path would be: `/run/user/1001`, and so on.

Just like:

> /run/user/1001/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=YOURUSERNAME

YOURUSERNAME is the prefix you are using to login to google.

Comment: That helped!! 

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, if you are in Desktop

1. Open "Files" program
2. In the Files windows, From left menu bar click
   on google drive folder menu to open drive on the right pane
3. In the right pane, in the top center click on the google drive folder name to open a down menu
4. From down menu click on "Open in Terminal" menu
5. Terminal will open with a prompt that is in the format
   "YOUR_PC_NAME:GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_PATH$".
6. GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_PATH
   is your desired folder. See example below.

For example, Terminal will display following prompt:

```
username@pc-name:/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=yourgoogleusername$
```

In the above example,  "`/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=yourgoogleusername`" is your desired path.